# Place different applications in Google Cloud under the same domain assigning subdomains for each one

Tags: google-cloud-platform, subdomain, google-app-engine, google-cloud-dns, google-cloud-run

I'm asking an opinion or some guide for this problem. I have a couple of applications in Google Cloud Platform that I need to place under the same domain (let's call it mydomain.com), using a different subdomain for each one, like this:

1. App 1 running on Cloud Run: **mydomain.com**  →  https://my-first-project-5yknbkcx2a-rj.a.run.app
2. App 2 running on Cloud Run: **subdomain1.mydomain.com**  →  https://my-second-project-3gwpgnrz9e-rj.a.run.app
3. App 3 running on App Engine: **subdomain2.mydomain.com**  →  https://my-third-project.rj.r.appspot.com/

And so on...

I tried following the "Mapping custom domains" guides like [this for Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/mapping-custom-domains?hl=en) and [this for App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/mapping-custom-domains), but I don't understand how can I do this across multiple projects.

How can I achieve this? Should I use another Google Cloud service like Network Services > Cloud DNS and/or Network Services > Load balancing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show what you tried and the error. The domain must be verified in each project. You can then map custom domains.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There are no error yet, I just don't understand how to make this work. If I configure my domain in a project (running an application in App Engine for example), how can I configure a subdomain of this same domain in a second project without affecting the first?

Comment: One subdomain does not affect another subdomain. Once you have configured something and have a problem, post a question.

Comment: One common thing I can think of is to manage your DNS records. By assigning your "mydomain.com" as an A record and your "subdomain.mydomain.com" a CNAME for example. As I understand your question, you want to set up an alias to your primary domain with a subdomain. If you want to expound on how to manage DNS records you can check this out. https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/records#before_you_begin